# Can you add a light source in blender using python

Tags: python, rendering, blender, light

Alright, I'm totally new to Blender and am just looking for some good tutorials on how to use python to control it. I want to be able to add/remove/edit light sources via python methods... can this be done? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which version of Blender are you running?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Blender 2.80** broke the old API, most steps changed. Updated code below.

```
import bpy

# create light datablock, set attributes
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="light_2.80", type='POINT')
light_data.energy = 30

# create new object with our light datablock
light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="light_2.80", object_data=light_data)

# link light object
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

# make it active 
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = light_object

#change location
light_object.location = (5, 5, 5)

# update scene, if needed
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get() 
dg.update()
```

Answer (score 12):

Answer is Yes!

Look at the recent [Python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Lamp.html#bpy.types.Lamp).

The example below creates a new Lamp object and puts it at the default location (5, 5, 5) in the current scene:

(*Blender 2.63*)

The script should look like this:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

# Create new lamp datablock
lamp_data = bpy.data.lamps.new(name="New Lamp", type='POINT')

# Create new object with our lamp datablock
lamp_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="New Lamp", object_data=lamp_data)

# Link lamp object to the scene so it'll appear in this scene
scene.objects.link(lamp_object)

# Place lamp to a specified location
lamp_object.location = (5.0, 5.0, 5.0)

# And finally select it make active
lamp_object.select = True
scene.objects.active = lamp_object
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. I'm not running any version just yet but will probably just use the lasted release.

Comment: I think I will, I'm not a big artist... so it should be a blast trying to get my creative side to come out :) Are there any really good resources to learning blender that you know of?

Comment: @innov83r Also, there is a SE site for blender.. http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know how to add light in blender 2.80 python API. It seems the API has changed to Light, but I have not got it work yet.